# How can i find out what C# version I'm programming with in Visual Studio Community?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to make sure I'm using C# 7.0 or higher. Does anyone know an easy way of checking this? I use Visual Studio Community on a MacBook and cannot seem to find an easy way of checking or setting language preferences.

Thanks

Comment: You can find it in Help->about but im marking this as off-topic

Comment: For a particular project: Properties -> Build -> Advanced... -> Language Version

Comment: @styx I don't think it is a duplicate because I'm referring to Visual Studio Community on a MacBook which doesn't have those options...? I have looked at Help as well and couldn't find it

Answer (score -1):

you dhuld edit the project file and add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>7.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate because I'm referring to Visual Studio Community on a MacBook which doesn't have those options...?

Comment: @jordantomiko you still have a .csproj file and that is what you should edit

Answer (score -1):

Normally you use the latest installed version (depending on the .Net framework) in Visual Studio.
If you want to change it, go to the advanced build setting (project -> properties -> build)

In the advanced build settings you also see all installed versions of C# (also the latest), therefore you can also check it there.

Comment: Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier better?

Comment: The question is already marked as duplicate. Your answer doesn't add extra value.